# Firebase hosting " An unexpected error has occurred"

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am trying to host my website and i logout from my old account and login to new account and it ask to update firebase then i try to update then it as to update npm then i do that but i am unable to continue because it is showing below error

```
 What do you want to use as your public directory? youqq
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? File youqq/index.html already exists. Overwrite? Yes
✔  Wrote youqq/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...

    Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

ubuntu 14.04 lts
 node -v v7.6.0
 npm -v 6.2.0
 firebase -V 4.0.0

Comment: problem solved after setting firebase.json permission to 777